# Handle file operations with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Currently I'm developing a persistence library for Android in Kotlin. In my code I have to handle file operations (read, write, etc.) which I would like to perform asynchronously for performance reasons. I thought that I could do this with the new coroutine feature of Kotlin 1.3

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    writeFileAsync(file, bytes)
}

private suspend fun writeFileAsync(file: File, bytes: ByteArray) {
    try {
        file.writeBytes(bytes)
    }  catch (e: Exception) {
        throw PersistenceException(e)
    }
}
```

Let's say I'm in the situation where the user has changed an object which is now persisted with the code above and he closes the app **before** the coroutine is finished. Of course I do not want to stop the coroutine due to data loss but is that okay here or am I leaking the coroutine then?

I'm also not sure how to block all other operations (maybe from other threads or processes) to that file while the coroutine is running so if you have ideas for that as well please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote doesn't use coroutine suspension at all. It just submits a block of code to some default common thread pool, which is something you don't need coroutines for. You can also write

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit {
    file.writeBytes(bytes)
}
```

and you don't need the coroutines dependency.

However, if you want to wait for the completion of the IO operation and follow it with some GUI operations, then coroutines will help you. You can write

```
this.launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        file.writeBytes(bytes)
    }
    updateGui()
}
```

This won't prevent the user from closing the app while the operations are in progress, however. That's another level of challenge and to achieve it, you must more deeply decouple the operations from your Activity, `WorkManager` seems to be the most modern choice.

Comment: Or we can start with a background service in onStop (and may turn it to foreground on the fly when the activity that's bound to it is destroyed).

Answer (score 0):

First, code you perform in coroutine is not more performant. It's probably even a bit less performant. But it's more concurrent.

Second, if the user terminates the app, all its threads will shut down. Since coroutines are based on a thread pool, they will also stop. If you want for something to continue working in the background, use something like a Service instead.

Third, if you want to acquire a lock on a file, use [FileLock](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileLock)

Comment: Thank you for the `FileLock` hint. I read the documentation and I find this paragraph confusing: _File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine._ Isn't that a problem for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

Use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) to do your job in the background when the app can be terminated.